# Magento 2.X: Add text to customer registration form

Tags: magento2.3

I need to add some text on the customer registration page site/customer/account/create/

How would be the right way to do so? It's just some information text in 3 languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To edit the text on the site/customer/account/create/ page you can go to

**app/design/frontend/vendor/theme/Magento_Customer/templates/form/register.phtml**

On this page you can edit Personal Information, Sign-In Information, etc. If you would like to edit the First Name and Last Name then you need to go to

**app/design/frontend/vendor/theme/Magento_Customer/templates/widget/name.phtml**

Additionally if you would like to add text at the end of the form, before the **Create an Account** button, then you can edit this page

**app/design/frontend/vendor/theme/Magento_Customer/templates/additionalinfocustomer.phtml**

Comment: I just need to add some text to the bottom of the page with some information about the registration and so on.

Comment: I don't have the page:
app/design/frontend/vendor/theme/Magento_Customer/templates/additionalinfocustomer.phtml

But I have this one:
/vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/templates/form/

Comment: Do you have a custom theme installed or are you using the Luma or Blank theme? Do not edit anything in the vendor folder. It will be erased anytime you update Magento

Comment: Depending on the theme you are using, go to app/design/frontend/your_vendor_name/your_theme_name/ and create a folder called Magento_Customer. Then go to your vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/templates folder. Copy the templates folder and everything in it, paste it inside the Magento_Customer folder you just made. Now edit the files I mentioned above. After making changes you will have to save them and Flush Static Files Cache (assuming you are in developer mode)

Comment: I am using Infortis ultimo theme: app/design/frontend/Infortis/ultimo/ - in that folder there is folders like: etc, Infortis_Ultimo, media and web. So inside the ultimo folder I make the Magento-Customer folder?

Comment: Now I have a folder: app/design/frontend/Infortis/ultimo/Magento_Customer/templates/form/ - I have changed the register.phtml, run php bin/magento setup:di:compile and tried to refresh my homepage.... nothing.

Comment: Got it!!! :) . after flush the static files the text came!!!! Now, I just need to make 3 text languages. Can I do that with the Custom Variables?